# CUDA grid dimension maxima - where are they defined?

Tags: cuda, constants, dimensions

The [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) gives non-device-specific maxima for grid dimensions in blocks: 2^31 - 1 for the x dimension, 2^16 - 1 for the y and z dimensions (table 15, as of CUDA 11.3).

My question: Where are these values defined, in code? I also looked at the driver API entry on [cudaLaunchKernel](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html), and it doesn't mention such constants either. I searched for 65535, for "<< 16" and for "<<16" in the CUDA header files, and no luck there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not defined in code.  They are a property of the device, the checking is at runtime (this is easily demonstrable), and the checking is done against properties retrieved from the device in question.

You can study the `deviceQuery` sample code to see how it might work.

Comment: So, you're saying there are no maxima we should be assume? Anything that fits in a dim3 is legitimate?

Comment: You already know that there are limits. The proper thing to do is to test any work at runtime, if you are concerned about limits. You handle it programmatically. There are no guarantees in the CUDA programming model that I know of, that a future GPU will not be limited to (1,1,1) grid dimension. In practice, nobody I know of worries about that. To be pedantic, you test at runtime.

Comment: I actually wanted to make some initial checks during command-line argument parsing, before I know which device is asked for and whether there are any devices on the system at all.